# Apache reverse proxy for Node sever

Tags: node.js, apache, reverse-proxy

I have a apache-based server running on `https://example.com` and inside of it a node application running on port 3000. Requests can be succesufully sent to `https://example.com:3000`, however, since I am planning to run multiple applications, I would like to set-up some reverse proxy for different applications. In order to do it I added the following lines to the apache conf file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin foo@example.com
    ServerName example.com

    ProxyRequests off

    <Proxy *>
            Order deny,allow
            Allow from all
    </Proxy>

    <Location /myapp1>
            ProxyPass http://localhost:3000
            ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:3000
    </Location>

    <Location /myapp2>
            ProxyPass http://localhost:3010
            ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:3010
    </Location>

</VirtualHost>
```

This approach does not seem to be working as requests to `https://example.com/myapp1` are not returning anything.

**Update**

After some debugging, I found out that the `.conf` file was actually being included inside a `<VirtualHost>` tag which was triggering the error (nested `<VirtualHost>` tags). Now I simply have the following:

```
ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyVia Full
<Proxy *>
   Require all granted
</Proxy>

<Location /myapp1>
   ProxyPass http://127.0.0.1:3000
   ProxyPassReverse http://127.0.0.1:3000
</Location>
<Location /myapp2>
   ProxyPass http://127.0.0.1:3010
   ProxyPassReverse http://127.0.0.1:3010
</Location>
```

Now when I hit `https://example.com/myapp1` I get Not Found - 500 Internal Server Error. Which at least show that routing is being recognized. Any ideas how to proceed with the debugging process?

Any ideas how to properly set up it

Comment: Port 80 is for http, Port 443 for https.

Comment: I had already tried 443 but nothing changed.

Comment: Have you enabled the site.conf  something as  `a2ensite site.conf`

Comment: `a2ensite` gives me commant not found in CentOS.

Comment: @SandeepPatel I updated my answer. Now there seems to be an internal error in the server.

Comment: @vtolentino pls check node  server logs now

Comment: @vtolentino also share code snippet for node server basically routing part and static content

Comment: @SandeepPatel node server is not receiving the requests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to fix my problem last week. The following line of code was missing from my reverse proxy configuration:

```
SSLProxyEngine on
```

Thanks for all the help.